# timeline (animate package) flickers to first tranparency when using JavaScript

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate, javascript

This is somehow a follow-up to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162735/timeline-and-animate-package/163615) question.

I am using some `tikz` drawing which I would like to animate using the `animate` package. The animation should start at the beginning, run through to the end of the animation and then jump to a frame somewhere in the middle and loop that last half of the frames.

Consider the following MWE which I build out of the mentioned question:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

% mytimeline.txt
\begin{filecontents*}{mytimeline.txt}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------  
%[*]:[new frame rate]:[<list of transparencies>][:<JavaScript>]  
% `*' in the first column pauses animation
%-------------------------------------------------------------------  
::0
::1
::2
::3
::4 
::5 
::6 
::7 
::8 
::9
::9:  anim.myAnim.frameNum=5; %After last frame, return to frame #5
\end{filecontents*} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{center} 
\begin{animateinline}[ 
  label=myAnim, 
  autoplay, loop,  
  width=\linewidth, 
  begin={\begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}}, 
  end={\end{minipage}}, 
  timeline=mytimeline.txt
]{4}% 
%create "transparencies", to be arranged according to timeline 
  \multiframe{10}{Number=0+1}{% 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \i in {0.1, 0.2, ..., 180} 
        \draw (\i:2) -- (\i+180:2);
      \node[white, font=\Huge] at (0,0) {\Number};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  } 
\end{animateinline}% 
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

The `timeline.txt` lets the animation start from the beginning and then loop the last 5 frames.

The animation itself here only draws the frame number and some hundred strokes to slow down display so you can see what I see with the real thing: **After getting to the last frame, the animation briefly displays the very first frame and only then jumps to the 5th frame as commanded.**

How can I make the animation **not** show that wrong slide?

For the record: I'm using a recent pdflatex and Adobe Reader DC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame graphic (1800 radial lines simulating the filled circle) is quite demanding for AR's rendering engine. This may lead to a race between execution of `anim.myAnim.frameNum=5` and the loop trigger. If the latter happens before the frame number setting, the animation briefly jumps back to `#0`.

This situation can be avoided if we repeat the last frame once more at the end of the timeline, pushing the loop event further behind the forced jump:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

% mytimeline.txt
\begin{filecontents*}{mytimeline.txt}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------  
%[*]:[new frame rate]:[<list of transparencies>][:<JavaScript>]  
% `*' in the first column pauses animation
%-------------------------------------------------------------------  
::0
::1
::2
::3
::4 
::5 
::6 
::7 
::8 
::9
::9:  anim.myAnim.frameNum=5; %After last frame, return to frame #5
::9   % added
\end{filecontents*} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{center} 
\begin{animateinline}[ 
  label=myAnim, 
  autoplay, loop,  
  width=\linewidth, 
  begin={\begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}}, 
  end={\end{minipage}}, 
  timeline=mytimeline.txt
]{4}% 
%create "transparencies", to be arranged according to timeline 
  \multiframe{10}{Number=0+1}{% 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \i in {0.1, 0.2, ..., 180} 
        \draw (\i:2) -- (\i+180:2);
      \node[white, font=\Huge] at (0,0) {\Number};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  } 
\end{animateinline}% 
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

The same visual result and animation performance, but saving compilation time and PDF file size (the "circle" is typeset only once):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

% mytimeline.txt
\begin{filecontents*}{mytimeline.txt}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------  
%[*]:[new frame rate]:[<list of transparencies>][:<JavaScript>]  
% `*' in the first column pauses animation
%-------------------------------------------------------------------  
::0x0,1
::2
::3
::4 
::5
::6 
::7 
::8 
::9
::10
::10: anim.myAnim.frameNum=5; %After last frame, return to frame #5
::10
\end{filecontents*} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{center} 
\begin{animateinline}[ 
  label=myAnim, 
  autoplay, loop,
  width=\linewidth, 
  begin={\begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}}, 
  end={\end{minipage}}, 
  timeline=mytimeline.txt
]{4}% 
  %create "transparencies", to be arranged according to timeline 
  \begin{tikzpicture} % black "circle"
    \foreach \i in {0.1, 0.2, ..., 180} \draw (\i:2) -- (\i+180:2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \newframe
  \multiframe{10}{Number=0+1}{% numbers, to be overlaid
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
      \node[white, font=\Huge] at (0,0) {\Number};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  } 
\end{animateinline}% 
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```